# Can't call DeleteObject() on entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

Ok I have a console app with an app.config, and a web project with a web.config, both which have the same connection string set for my entity framework connection to my SQL Server 2008 database. My entity framwork edmx is in a class library of its own which both the console app and web project reference.

In code behind in the web project I can access all calls, e.g myconn.AddToTable() and moremyconn.DeleteObject()

In the console app however I can only access AddTo calls but not delete?! Any ideas? THanks.

Answer (score 1):

its ok i figured it - i was missing a system.data.entity reference in my console app

Comment: Mark your question as answer.